# How can I make my app bottom menu full width with html and css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The mobile version on my website has a bottom navbar menu that looks like an app bottom menu. It looks fine in all devices except in the ones who have 320px width size.  In these, the navbar doesn't take the screen's full width but it rather gets cut. (I'm using Bootstrap 4).

This is what it should look like:

[image]

This is what's happening in 320px width devices:

[image]

This is what it looks like when I add `width: 100vw`:

[image]

My HTML:

```css
// Tablets and Phones (768 and down) //
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom {
    display: flex;
    background-color: $white;
    height: 78px;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding-top: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0px -4px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px -4px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px -4px 27px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn i {
    color: $footer-link;
    font-size: 1.2em;
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn p {
    display: block;
    color: $footer-link;
    font-size: 0.6em;
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish-container {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 40px;
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish-container i {
    color: $white;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    padding-top: 16px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish {
    background-color: $secondary-color;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nh-mobile-footer-bottom-publish-label {
    color: $footer-link;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    margin-top: 9px;
  }
  .nh-footer-menu-message-bubble {
    background: $error;
    border-radius: 0.8em;
    color: $white;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 20px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 3em;
    left: 0.8em;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.5.3 CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row fixed-bottom nh-mobile-footer-bottom">

  <!-- Map -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn pl-4" id="nhMobileMenuMap">
    <i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    <p>Mapa</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Filtros -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn" id="nhMobileMenuFilters">
    <i class="fal fa-filter"></i>
    <p>Filtros</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Publicar-->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#publicationServiceModal" id="nhMobileMenuPublishBtn">
    <i class="fa fa-plus nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish"></i>
    <p class="nh-mobile-footer-bottom-publish-label">Publicar</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Mis servicios -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn" id="nhMobileMenuMiServicios">
    <i class="fal fa-user-tag"></i>
    <p>Mis servicios</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Messages -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn pr-4" id="nhMobileMenuMessages">
    <i class="fal fa-comment"></i>
    <p>Mensajes<span class="nh-footer-menu-message-bubble">2</span></p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Used background color & hover effect to show the class cover the area - You can see that by removing `*{}` or any other CSS to see behavior
- Used `!important` to override the original **Bootstrap CSS code**

```css
* {
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  overflow:auto !important;
}

.nh-mobile-footer-bottom {
  width: 100% !important;
  display: block !important;
}

button {
  float: left !important;
  width: 20% !important;
  height: 60px !important;
  font-size: 11px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: blue !important;
  color: white !important
}

#nhMobileMenuMap {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
#nhMobileMenuMessages {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 4.5.3 CDN -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="row fixed-bottom nh-mobile-footer-bottom">

  <!-- Map -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn pl-4" id="nhMobileMenuMap">
    <i class="fal fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
    <p>Mapa</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Filtros -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn" id="nhMobileMenuFilters">
    <i class="fal fa-filter"></i>
    <p>Filtros</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Publicar-->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish-container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#publicationServiceModal" id="nhMobileMenuPublishBtn">
    <i class="fa fa-plus nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn-publish"></i>
    <p class="nh-mobile-footer-bottom-publish-label">Publicar</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Mis servicios -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn" id="nhMobileMenuMiServicios">
    <i class="fal fa-user-tag"></i>
    <p>Mis servicios</p>
  </button>

  <!-- Messages -->
  <button type="button" class="btn col nh-mobile-footer-bottom-btn pr-4" id="nhMobileMenuMessages">
    <i class="fal fa-comment"></i>
    <p>Mensajes<span class="nh-footer-menu-message-bubble">2</span></p>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work. I added `width: 100%; display: block;` to my `.nh-mobile-footer-bottom` class and it didn't work.

Comment: The thing that is interrupting here is the width of respective button you have . And you may try to reduce some width

Comment: The problem with your solution is that when I reduce the btn's width, even though they do fit width wise, the buttons are not longer well distributed horiontally.

Comment: What is the code you used in class `.nh-mobile-footer-bottom button` and `.nh-mobile-footer-bottom` in main code (not in `@media`)

Comment: `.nh-mobile-footer-bottom button {display: none};`

Comment: Now you can get what you want and style according to your will . But remember on very small screen it will show a scroll bar at bottom if you use `overflow:auto !important;` in `*{}`

Comment: Did you get another way round your question and get the answer

Comment: What problem are you facing now can you share pic of output using the above code